# Light: Intensity vs Brightness

Tags: optics, intensity

Is the intensity or brightness of light the same idea? In other words, when we are observing [Malus's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus%27s_law_and_other_properties), are we looking at the "brightness" of light? If they are not the same quantity, how can we qualitatively see the intensity of light and distinguish it from the qualitative visualization of brightness?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, [*brightness*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colchar.html#c3) is defined in optics as a component of color.

Therefore it depends not only on the intensity of the light, but on our perception of it. It is more closely related to [luminous intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity) than to [radiant intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity). For a beam with a given spectrum, however, the luminous and radiant intensities will be related by fixed proportionality.

For example, we could observe Malus's law using infrared light, but this light would have no perceived brightness because we can't see infrared light.

Answer (score 9):

[Intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics)) is the power per unit area; it is a physical quantity. [Brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness) involves how the human visual system *perceives* light, and it is not a physical quantity.

Comment: In general, better to avoid using the word  "Brightness"  -- for example see that note at the bottom of the referenced page about yet another definition.  Stick with radiance, illuminance,  and absolute vs  photopic vs scotopic sensing.